# What is the difference between setting the DTC port range via Registry and dcomcnfg?

Tags: rpc, dcom, msdtc

I am confused about setting the port range for DTC communication. What is the difference (functionally) by setting the ports via dcomcnfg as described in [this NServiceBus Article](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/transactions-message-processing#distributed-transaction-coordinator) versus configuring them through the registry as described in this [Microsoft Support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/250367)? Is there any reason one would behave differently or are these completely different settings that just appear similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference*, as in both cases the `Ports` value under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet` Registry key is being modifying. The screenshot below shows the registry modification (captured using [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx)), which happens when setting the port range using DCOMCNFG:

[image: DCOMCNFG Registry Port Changes]

Anyhow, at some point in time, [Microsoft recommended to edit Registry directly instead](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/250367), due to a bug inside DCOMCNFG, which is documented under [KB201911](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201911) (notice that the statement below confirms DCOMCNFG is in fact modifying `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RPC\Internet\Ports`):

> When a port range is specified for a protocol, such as 4000-4010, the
>   value that is written to the registry key
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RPC\Internet\Ports (named REG_MULTI_SZ) is
>   "4000 - 4010." A space is added preceding and succeeding the "-".

There is another Microsoft KB ([KB217351](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/217351)), which refers to this bug, and suggests the following:

> If you used the DCOMCNFG utility to configure port restrictions, you
>   may be encountering a known DCOMCNFG bug. Rather than use the DCOMCNFG
>   utility, use Regedt32.exe to configure the port restrictions as
>   described in the white paper.

*Therefore, unless you are using a non-supported version of Windows, which relies on Microsoft COM+ 2.0, the bug mentioned above is no longer applicable, and you are free to either use DCOMCNFG or edit `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RPC\Internet\Ports` directly